# In an Excel sheet compare columns to input data

Tags: excel-formula

if the IP address in column G2 (Tab1) = the IP address in column B (Tab2) then input data from column C (Tab2) in H2 (Tab1)

[Tabs in sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPKsi.gif)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you have a read of this link please:  [ask].  By the sound of it you need a `VLOOKUP` (can't see the image in the link so may be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

a vlookup or match index would work well for this, however, upon reading your question if your looking for full automation i think macros would be able to better handle this if you chose to develop it into a more elaborate task.

a vlookup would try to refrence and duplication infromation stored in another table

```
h2=iferror(vlookup($g2,$b:$c,2,false),"")
```

this will try to find a match between g2 and all of b column, then if a match is found take the "2" second column after "b" (which is "c") and put it in h2. last, if there is nothing there, just leave it blank ""

if your going into something more intense though such as data logging or something you want more application out of id go with a macro(an automated series of tasks you would've had to do manually)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  'pretending every time you datalog you store the new entry in g2
If Target.Address(0, 0) = "G2" Then
    For Each a In Range(Range("B2"), Range("B2").End(xlDown))
        If a.Value = Range("G2") Then
            Range("H2").Value = a.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next a
End If
End Sub
```

this macro says anytime theres a change to g2 scan b2 and anything below it for a match. then if a match is found copy it over to h2.

If you need help with vba just PM me

Cheers

Comment: Thanx this worked great.  I had to make one change, $g2, $b:$c... to $g2,"TAB2 name"!b:c:...